# Find duplicates on multiple columns in a SQL table in order to create UNIQUE index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, duplicates

I created a index called `abc` on a table called `table` with a `PRIMARY KEY` called `id` and three others `INT` columns `a`, `b` and `c` that can be `NULL`.

Now I need this index to be UNIQUE, so I tried :

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP INDEX abc, ADD UNIQUE abc (a, b, c);
```

But I have duplicates, so MySQL answers :

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1-2-3' for key 'abc'
```

I probably have a lot of those duplicates, so I'm looking for an easy way to search & destroy them all. My first guess has been :

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY abc
```

But sadly it seems that you can't group by indexes.

Is there an easy way to find those duplicates, keep one line of each duplicate and delete the others ?

EDIT :

- `table` as an `id` field that is a `PRIMARY KEY`
- `a`, `b` and `c` are all `INT` and can be `NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to eliminate duplicates first, just use the [`IGNORE` option for `ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) to do exactly what you want;

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table DROP INDEX abc, ADD UNIQUE abc (a, b, c);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a98f/1).

> If IGNORE is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. If IGNORE is specified, only one row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted.

...and always remember to back up your data before running potentially destructive SQL from random people on the Internet.

Comment: This si simple and elegant, and it's going to save me a lot of time. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a simple way _if all duplicates are equivalent_. If they're not, you'll need to have some kind of criteria which row is "better" to keep and do the delete using a query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a,b,c
FROM table 
GROUP BY a,b,c
HAVING count(*)>1
```

Comment: This is a nice way to see all duplicates. I forgot to say that a, b and c can be NULL and should not be considered as duplicate where they are, but you can fixed this by adding `WHERE `a` IS NOT NULL AND `b` IS NOT NULL and `c` IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

try this to find dupes

```
Select a, b, c
From table 
group By a, b, c
Having Count(*) > 1
```

If there is already a unique key column (say its `pkColumn`) on this table, 
you can do this to delete extra dupes.

```
Delete table
From table t
Where pkColumn <>
   (Select Min(pkColumn)
    From table
    where a = t.a
      and b = t.b
      and c = t.c)
```

Comment: The first query is a nice way to see all duplicates. I forgot to say that a, b and c can be NULL and should not be considered as duplicate where they are, but you can fixed this by adding `WHERE `a` IS NOT NULL AND `b` IS NOT NULL and `c` IS NOT NULL. I didn't try the second query because choosen answer was good enough for me, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have several records that aren't in this situation.

To avoid losing data

```
CREATE table duplicates SELECT MIN(id) as id, a, b, c,  COUNT(1) as nduplicates 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY a,b,c 
HAVING COUNT(1)>1;

UPDATE yourtable t, duplicates d 
SET t.a='toDelete(or some value that you can easy identify from the rest)' 
WHERE d.a=t.a and d.b=t.b and d.c=t.c 
and d.id!=t.id;

DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE a='toDelete';
```

and then drop duplicates table.